# How to create background from few images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

I am developing the application based on existing html version and don't know how to create following background for my scroll view. 
I have one image for the top
[image]

one that should repeat to the bottom few times
[image]

and one image in the bottom
[image]

As I understand I must create an empty image with scroll view size, draw the header then calculate how many times to draw the middle image and draw the bottom image. Finally I must apply the created image to background. Am I right?

Please don't waste your time to write the complete code, I'll do it myself, I just need to know whether I am on the right way or doing completely wrong and what is the best place in the code to do that?

Please advice

Comment: Why not just overlap the elements, like for example your background can be an imageview and you have other elements overlapping it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand I must create an empty image with scroll view size, draw the header

1. you can add a `UIImageView` with the `image` property set to your header image.

> then calculate how many times to draw the middle image and draw the bottom image;

1. it is easier to just say:

   ```
   UIView* middleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:];
   middleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPattern:[UIImage imageNamed:...]];
   ```

This has the advantage that you do not need to calculate anything and the image will simply repeat itself to fill the `middleView`. Only ensure that the image width is the same as the view width, and the view height a integer multiple of the image height.

> Finally I must apply the created image to background. Am I right?

1. this goes like 1.

Comment: It's going to be a scroll view. I suppose he wants the background to scroll along with the content of the scroll view.